# How do I create an interactive Powershell instance from C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a Powershell script that requires user interaction.  I can call powershell.exe from C# using System.Diagnostics.Process and pass the scripts path as a parameter but I would like the script to be an embedded resource of the project.  I tried creating a Runspace  (see below) and running the script but because the script requires user interaction I receive an exception.

```
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();            
        var resourceName = "mynamespace.myscriptfile.ps1";
        string result = "";

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        //Create Powershell Runspace
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        // Create pipeline and add commands
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(result);

        // Execute Script
        Collection<PSObject> results = new Collection<PSObject>();
        try
        {
            results = pipeline.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            results.Add(new PSObject((object)ex.Message));
        }

        runspace.Close();
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Is there a way to either pass the embedded resource to powershell.exe using *System.Diagnostics.Process* or is there a way to Invoke the script from C# where the user can interact?

UPDATE:
It seems to me that I may be able to use an implementation of the abstract class PSHost along with using the PSHostUserInterface property correctly, I may be able to create a Runspace that takes the PSHost implementation as a parameter to use the native Powershell console.  I have been trying to test the idea but I'm not quite sure how to implement the abstract class.

Below is a sample of code that I obtained from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/hosting/host01-sample). I am confused with a couple of things.  If it matters I will be creating the Runspace in a console application with a namespace called: *WebRequirements* in the *Program* class.

1. private Host01 program;  (Would Host01 be Program?)
2. PSHostUserInterface (Is this where I would dictate that I want to use a native Powershell host and if so how would I do that?)

   internal class MyHost : PSHost
   {
       /// 
       /// A reference to the PSHost implementation.
       /// 
       private Host01 program;

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// The culture information of the thread that created
   /// this object.
   /// </summary>
   private CultureInfo originalCultureInfo =
       System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

   /// <summary>
   /// The UI culture information of the thread that created
   /// this object.
   /// </summary>
   private CultureInfo originalUICultureInfo =
       System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;

   /// <summary>
   /// The identifier of this PSHost implementation.
   /// </summary>
   private Guid myId = Guid.NewGuid();

   /// <summary>
   /// Initializes a new instance of the MyHost class. Keep
   /// a reference to the host application object so that it
   /// can be informed of when to exit.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="program">
   /// A reference to the host application object.
   /// </param>
   public MyHost(Host01 program)
   {
       this.program = program;
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Return the culture information to use. This implementation
   /// returns a snapshot of the culture information of the thread
   /// that created this object.
   /// </summary>
   public override System.Globalization.CultureInfo CurrentCulture
   {
       get { return this.originalCultureInfo; }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Return the UI culture information to use. This implementation
   /// returns a snapshot of the UI culture information of the thread
   /// that created this object.
   /// </summary>
   public override System.Globalization.CultureInfo CurrentUICulture
   {
       get { return this.originalUICultureInfo; }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// This implementation always returns the GUID allocated at
   /// instantiation time.
   /// </summary>
   public override Guid InstanceId
   {
       get { return this.myId; }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Return a string that contains the name of the host implementation.
   /// Keep in mind that this string may be used by script writers to
   /// identify when your host is being used.
   /// </summary>
   public override string Name
   {
       get { return "MySampleConsoleHostImplementation"; }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// This sample does not implement a PSHostUserInterface component so
   /// this property simply returns null.
   /// </summary>
   public override PSHostUserInterface UI
   {
       get { return null; }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Return the version object for this application. Typically this
   /// should match the version resource in the application.
   /// </summary>
   public override Version Version
   {
       get { return new Version(1, 0, 0, 0); }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Not implemented by this example class. The call fails with
   /// a NotImplementedException exception.
   /// </summary>
   public override void EnterNestedPrompt()
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException(
           "The method or operation is not implemented.");
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Not implemented by this example class. The call fails
   /// with a NotImplementedException exception.
   /// </summary>
   public override void ExitNestedPrompt()
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException(
           "The method or operation is not implemented.");
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// This API is called before an external application process is
   /// started. Typically it is used to save state so the parent can
   /// restore state that has been modified by a child process (after
   /// the child exits). In this example, this functionality is not
   /// needed so the method returns nothing.
   /// </summary>
   public override void NotifyBeginApplication()
   {
       return;
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// This API is called after an external application process finishes.
   /// Typically it is used to restore state that a child process may
   /// have altered. In this example, this functionality is not
   /// needed so the method returns nothing.
   /// </summary>
   public override void NotifyEndApplication()
   {
      return;
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Indicate to the host application that exit has
   /// been requested. Pass the exit code that the host
   /// application should use when exiting the process.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="exitCode">The exit code to use.</param>
   public override void SetShouldExit(int exitCode)
   {
       this.program.ShouldExit = true;
       this.program.ExitCode = exitCode;
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: 3rd option: create a popup (gui) in powershell asking for input.

Comment: @T-Me  How?  Also, I want the results of my script to be displayed in the native powershell host as I have quite a bit of formatting that was created for such a window.

Comment: For easy interaction (Yes,No,Cancel) all you need is a [MassageBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons?view=netframework-4.7.2). If you need more, like entering something you would need a real GUI like [WinForms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/index) or [WPF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/index). I would go for WinForms for most easy tasks. WPF is more capable (databinding) and modern, but way harder to learn. However most of the formatting will be lost, since the consol itself is not displayed.

Comment: @T-Me I need the native PowerShell window.